# Resource found but does not get executed

Tags: apache-wink

I have customized Apache Wink to use an XML provider, basically overriden the standard JacksonJsonProvider.

See http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/jackson-xml-provider for details

The provider seems to work and the resource gets correctly recognized, but the resource method does not get executed.

Do I need to set something on the client ? Apache Wink returns HTTP 204 (No content).

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the resource signature mismatch. By default, the rest client which I was using used an "accept" text/plain by default whereas the resource was returning "application/xml"